# No se activa la función con el gancho woocommerce_order_status_changed para obtener el cambio de estado

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin

Estoy realizando un plugin en wordpress, y cuando quiero comprobar como cambia el estado de un producto al realizar el proceso de compra, he intentado crear una función que he asignado al hook
*woocommerce_order_status_changed*

```
function evaluateStateChange($order_id, $old_, $new_)
    {
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

        $paymentMethod = $order->get_payment_method();
        $status = $order->get_status();

        if (($paymentMethod == 'bacs' && $status == 'on-hold') || ($paymentMethod != 'bacs' && $status == 'processing')) {
            $order_items = $order->get_items();
            foreach ($order_items as $item) {
                $data = $item->get_data();

                $res_ = get_post_meta($data['product_id'], '_product_attributes', true);
               
               ................


            }
        }
    }

    add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'evaluateStateChange', 10, 3);
```

El método está incompleto, ya que primero quiero probar si entra en el método al finalizar la compra. Si entra, ya se realizará en su totalidad. El problema que tengo es que ni siquiera entra al método (comprobado mediante debuggeo). ¿Es necesario realizar algunos pasos adicionales? ¿Por qué no entra en el método al finalizar la compra? Gracias de antemano

Comment: De acuerdo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47081351/2412893) (en inglés), el evento debería ser `woocommerce_thankyou`; supongo que el que estás usando aplicaría para cancelaciones u otros cambios de estado en la orden.

Comment: Pues voy  a probar. La verdad es que (todavía) no he conseguido el objetivo. Gracias por el aporte.